# Live page preview by hover for wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Is there a way or code so I can preview the page live by hovering over the link to it? I know of the plugin [WP Live Preview Links](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-live-preview-links/), but it runs slow. Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, without caching it would load slowly, because:

- It needs to load the external page
- Your browser (or some server-side renderer) needs to render that page

That plugin renders sites in iframe, so the whole load goes to the client side. Some sites have `iframe` disabled, so you **will** have issues with that.

A better approach would be to cache the previews. So, once your article is posted, you execute a script on the server that filters all links in text and then creates previews for each link.

This way, when the user hovers the link, he'll see an image and will not need to load an entire webpage. The previews will not be "live", but you can refresh them, let's say, hourly.